# How to highlight end of line with line number

Tags: shell, awk

I want to highlight the end of line with line numbers shown in a different color. I know the command for displaying line number i.e `awk '{print $0","NR;}' file` but don't know how to highlight end of line. Anyone who can help me with that? I want to do both in a single command if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight"?

Comment: Mean the end of line show in different color

Comment: Are you saying you want to append colored line numbers to each line? Do you also need them to be aligned in a column?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ seq 4 6 | awk -v red="$(tput setaf 1)" -v reset="$(tput sgr0)" '{print $0, red NR reset}'
4 1
5 2
6 3
```

You obviously can't see the colors above so here's the output with the color-changing escapes shown just so you can see that they are present:

```
$ seq 4 6 | awk -v red="$(tput setaf 1)" -v reset="$(tput sgr0)" '{print $0, red NR reset}' | cat -v
4 ^[[31m1^[(B^[[m
5 ^[[31m2^[(B^[[m
6 ^[[31m3^[(B^[[m
```

Answer (score 0):

If your terminal supports ANSI escape codes, you can try this:

```
awk '{ print $0, "\x1b[7m" NR "\x1b[0m" }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
perl -mTerm::ANSIColor=color -lne 'print $_, color("red"), $., color("reset")'
```

or

```
perl -mTerm::ANSIColor=RESET,RED -lne 'print $_, RED, $., RESET'
```

In `perl`, `$_` is the current line and `$.` is the line number.  `RED` and `RESET` are fairly self explanatory.  From the documentation for ANSIColor, your options are:

```
  CLEAR           RESET             BOLD            DARK
  FAINT           ITALIC            UNDERLINE       UNDERSCORE
  BLINK           REVERSE           CONCEALED

  BLACK           RED               GREEN           YELLOW
  BLUE            MAGENTA           CYAN            WHITE
  BRIGHT_BLACK    BRIGHT_RED        BRIGHT_GREEN    BRIGHT_YELLOW
  BRIGHT_BLUE     BRIGHT_MAGENTA    BRIGHT_CYAN     BRIGHT_WHITE

  ON_BLACK        ON_RED            ON_GREEN        ON_YELLOW
  ON_BLUE         ON_MAGENTA        ON_CYAN         ON_WHITE
  ON_BRIGHT_BLACK ON_BRIGHT_RED     ON_BRIGHT_GREEN ON_BRIGHT_YELLOW
  ON_BRIGHT_BLUE  ON_BRIGHT_MAGENTA ON_BRIGHT_CYAN  ON_BRIGHT_WHITE
```